# Can't display images in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to display an image to tkinter window, but this code doesn't work, Thanks for your Help!

```
photo = PhotoImage('images/button.png')
label = Label(image=photo)
label.image = photo
label.pack()
```

Comment: Should be `photo = PhotoImage(file='images/button.png')`.

Comment: That worked! Thanks, I didn't even noticed that..

Comment: Read up on [The Tkinter PhotoImage Class](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm)